# Find the radius of the circle in complex plane given by $|z - i| = 3|z +2i|$ where $z$ is a point on the circle.

Tags: complex-numbers, circles, absolute-value

I tried to arrange the following into the standard equation of the circle i.e $|z - z'| = r$ where $r$ is the radius, $z'$ is the centre and $z$ is a point on the circle.

I rearranged the following equation to $|z - i| / |z + 2i| = 3$.

Now I substituted $z = x + iy$ and rationalised the left hand side. After rationalising I could not arrange it to look like the standard form. Please share your solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Try squaring both sides, then substituting $z=x+iy$. Use $\left | z \right |^{2}=\overline{z}z$

Comment: this can be also solved by using apollonius circle https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjo1I2CmaDsAhWd6XMBHf_fANQQFjAHegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCircles_of_Apollonius&usg=AOvVaw0dam3cKq7P2lmOL__B1iYo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|z - i| = 3|z +2i|$

$x^2+(y-1)^2=9(x^2+(y+2)^2)$

$x^2+y^2-2y+1=9x^2+9y^2+36y+36$

$8x^2+8y^2+38y+35=0$

$x^2+y^2+\frac{19}{4}y+\frac {35}{8}=0$

$x^2+(y+\frac{19}{8})^2=\frac{81}{64}$

Circle is centered at $(0;-\frac{19}{8})$ with radius $r=\frac{9}{8}$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $9$ where there is a $3$ on the second line?

Comment: I will check now

Comment: @LPenguin - thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lion Heart and @LPenguin

Comment: @Aman Jain - you are welcome

Comment: How to do that? by the radius is 9/8 not 9rt2/4...
Also can you tell me how to write in symbols here? I am new...

Comment: Use $$ and \sqrt{ 2}

Comment: r^2  = -35 + (19/8)^2   --->

r^2  = 81/64   --->

r = 9/8

Answer (score 2):

Note that, if $z=x+yi$ with $x,y\in\Bbb R$,\begin{align}|z-i|=3|z+2i|&\iff x^2+(y-1)^2=9x^2+9(y+2)^2\\&\iff8x^2+8y^2+38y=-35\\&\iff8x^2+8\left(y+\frac{19}8\right)^2=\frac{81}8\\&\iff x^2+\left(y+\frac{19}8\right)^2=\left(\frac98\right)^2.\end{align}

Comment: Professor, I think it should be 9x^2 + 9(y + 2)^2 on the right hand side of the first line?

Comment: @AmanJain Quite right! I have edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:
$$|z-i|^2=9|z+2i|^2\,,$$
and expand this out using complex conjugation and factorize to obtain
$$8|z+\frac{19}{8}i|^2=-35+\frac{19^2}{8}\,,$$
and the radius becomes apparent.

Comment: When I compare it to the standard form, the value of radius comes out to be correct but I do not understand how did you reach second equation from first equation? I do not understand what identity you used there...

Comment: Hello Aman, I used complex conjugation, i.e., $|z-c|^2=|z|^2-z\overline{c}-\overline{z}c+|c|^2$. When you expand the square of your equation, you’d then observe that (after factoring out $8$) you obtain $c=-\frac{19}{8}i$ and you arrive at my final identity. (Of course, as you noted, the right-hand side is simply $\frac{9^2}{8}$.)

Answer (score 0):

If $|z-(a+ib)| = r|z-(c+id)|$ then
$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2
=r^2((x-c)^2+(y-d)^2)
$

so

$0
=(x^2+y^2)(r^2-1)+2x(a-r^2c)+2y(b-r^2d)+r^2(c^2+d^2)-a^2-b^2\\
=(x^2+y^2)(r^2-1)+2ux+2vy+w
$.

If $r^2=1$ then
$0=2ux+2vy+w
$, a straight line.

If $r^2\ne 1$ then,
if
$(u, v, w)_1
=(u, v, w)/(r^2-1),\\
0
= x^2+2u_1x+y^2+2v_1y+w_1\\
=(x-u_1)^2+(y-v_1)^2+w_1-u_1^2-v_1^2
$

Comment: sorry I don't understand this...